# sendto takes much time

Tags: c, sockets, raw-sockets

I'm trying communicate client-server without tcp's payload. I'm just using tcp's header as payload field which is 20 byte in default. I just realized cpu usage is very high for transfer big files I tried put some timer to every part of code. (I used rdtsc for it.) Result is I build packet's everything in 1000~ tick (I don't touch ipv4 checksum since kernel calculates it automatically); then I looked sendto time, it takes 100000~ tick (100x more than to build the packet). Is there any faster way to send raw tcp packet without sendto or a way to make sendto faster?

I measure sendto time like this:

```
timefirst = rdtsc()
sendto()
timesecond = rdtsc()
print timesecond - timefirst
```

I create my send socket with:

```
int mysocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP);
int one = 1;
const int *val = &one;
setsockopt(mysocket, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, val, sizeof(one));
```

Note: I'm talking about packet's time only on my side (sender program and kernel). It's not about about how slow it goes through wire, isp and routers.

Comment: I don't follow how you can use the TCP header for payload.  You could use a custom transport protocol on top of IP, with a 20-byte payload, but then you would need to choose a different protocol number, and the 20-byte payload would be just that -- payload -- not a TCP header.

Comment: I'm using tcp header for just fun it looks like broken packet in outside (like that packet doesn't have any data inside). Also I don't think sendto will take less time if i use own protocol since I already use raw socket, isn't it same in linux kernel? maybe I create raw socket wrong? @JohnBollinger

Comment: The TCP header contains information that both sender and receiver rely upon for handling the packet.  I am uncertain what parts of that are disabled on the sending side by using raw sockets, but no good can come from this approach.

Comment: Additionally, tinygrams tend to reduce network performance and increase load on all network components, including endpoints.  You are intentionally sending *nothing but* tinygrams.  That seems likely to be a contributor to your performance issue, though I suspect there are other factors, too.

Comment: I don't get any difference when i don't change TCP header (about sendto time). Also I tried create socket with socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW) (not TCP now right?) but it still takes same time in kernel mode.

Comment: Well, to send an IP packet to another place, there's a need to route it and get the MAC address of the target destination, which can involve (not always) an ARP roundrip to get the MAC address of the router/destination host to compose the ethernet header.

Comment: You have not included the amount of delay or the wire traffic output seen in the wire to be able to determine these timings...  How do you determine the destination address, is there also a DNS lookup to get the IP address?  That should imply another network roundtrip (the first time) to get the IP address of the destination host.  What's the duration of a tick?

Comment: I think someone deleted lot of comments in here. As reReply:
I don't measure anything about outside of my PC (like how fast it goes from wire or what happens at ISP) and I don't care it, I just measure `sendto()` time with `rdtsc()` and I'm trying to say `sendto()` is slow in CPU side. Since I only measure `sendto()`'s time how DNS lookup can effect `sendto()`'s time?

Answer (score 0):

Are you encountering Nagle's algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm ?

If so, you can try setting a socket option of `TCP_NODELAY` which might address data being sent more slowly than you expect.

Comment: I don't think that since rdtsc counts when cpu does work. I mean sleep(99999999) will don't have high rdtsc time since sleep almost doesn't use your cpu.
By the way I tried:

one = 1; setsockopt(mysocket, IPPROTO_IP, TCP_NODELAY, &one, sizeof(one);
one = 0; setsockopt(mysocket, IPPROTO_IP, TCP_NODELAY, &one, sizeof(one);
one = 1; setsockopt(mysocket, SOL_SOCKET, TCP_NODELAY, &one, sizeof(one);
one = 0; setsockopt(mysocket, SOL_SOCKET, TCP_NODELAY, &one, sizeof(one);

It didn't change anything about rdtsc's time

Comment: Nagle's algorithm is implemented in the TCP layer. If the TCP layer is bypassed by using raw-sockets, then Nagle's algorithm won't be used.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to send an IP packet to another place, there's a need to route it and get the MAC address of the target destination, which can involve (not always) an ARP roundtrip to get the MAC address of the router/destination host to compose the ethernet header.

You have not included the amount of delay (well you did, but you didn't specify the duration of a tick) or the wire traffic output seen in the wire to be able to determine these timings...  How do you determine the destination address, is there also a DNS lookup to get the IP address?  That should imply another network roundtrip (the first time) to get the IP address of the destination host.

In other plane, what are you actually measuring? the time it takes to `sendto(2)` to execute? the time the packet takes to be visible on the wire? the time it takes to reach the destination?  If so, are the source and target machines synchronized? how are they syncrhonzed in that case?

Why don't you actually show your code as the [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page shows?

Comment: Sorry for miss information. I just measure sendto time. I added how I measure sendto time to thread.

Comment: sendto needs to make an ARP request on cache miss (not always) due to translation of ip addresses into hardware addresses (MAC)

Comment: So how I can make it faster? Is there any other way for send raw packet?

Comment: @dawdawdddwq, well, you can use a `PF_PACKET` socket in linux, which will give you access to the ethernet level, but this is linux specific and you can go to an OS that doesn't have it.  This will require you to put the MAC addresses you want to use, and calculate yourself your checksums (well the ethernet can be calculated for you or you can even fake it) read about PACKET sockets in linux in the book [_Unix network programming_ from Stevens](https://www.amazon.es/UNIX-Network-Programming-Networking-Sockets/dp/013490012X/ref=pd_sim_14_2/260-6257430-4465836).

Comment: I used `PF_PACKET` and `ioctl`s for create socket. I verified I create ethernet layer from begin (I tried change source MAC and destination MAC and it worked). but sendto still takes same time @LuisColorado